# Can't load my ONNX model (converted from Pytorch) in OpenCV DNN

Tags: opencv, pytorch, onnx

As known, OpenCV DNN does not support Pytorch models (.pt). So, I followed the [Pytorch Documentation for converting my model to .onnx](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html) and then run with OpenCV DNN. Following this, i did this steps:
**1. First My NN definition in pytorch:**

```
class ModelTeste(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ModelTeste, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size = 20, stride=3)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 42, kernel_size=12, stride=2,)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(42, 24, kernel_size=9, stride=2)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(24, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=2)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten(1, 3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(144, 350)
        self.relu5 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.05)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(350, 350)
        self.relu6 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(350, 350)
        self.relu7 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(350, 400)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(F.pad(x, [8, 9, 8, 9]))
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.conv2(F.pad(x, [5, 5, 5, 5]))
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.conv3(F.pad(x, [3, 4, 3, 4]))
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.conv4(F.pad(x, [2, 2, 2, 2]))
        x = self.relu4(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu5(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu6(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.relu7(x)
        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)
        return x
    
modelteste = ModelTeste()

criterionteste = torch.nn.BCELoss()
optimizerteste = torch.optim.Adam(modelteste.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

**2. Then I load the state dictionary with:**

```
PATH = 'C:\\neokoros\\pytorchconversao\\statedict_modelnovo.pt'
batch_size = 64

# Initialize model with the pretrained weights
modelteste.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))

# set the model to inference mode
modelteste.eval()
```

**3. After this I created a dummy input and exported to ONNX:**

```
# Input to the model

x = torch.rand(1, 1, 120, 120, requires_grad=True)

torch.onnx.export(modelteste,               # model being run
                  x,                         # model input (or a tuple for multiple inputs)
                  "model1.onnx",   # where to save the model (can be a file or file-like object)
                  verbose=True,
                  export_params=True,        # store the trained parameter weights inside the model 
                  opset_version=12,          # the ONNX version to export the model to
                  do_constant_folding=True,  # whether to execute constant folding for optimization
                  input_names = ['input'],   # the model's input names
                  output_names = ['output'], # the model's output names
                  dynamic_axes={'input' : {0 : 'batch_size'},    # variable length axes
                                'output' : {0 : 'batch_size'}})
```

4. Then I just load and run my model with ONNXruntime for checking

```
model1 = onnx.load("model1.onnx")

print(onnx.helper.printable_graph(model1.graph)) #Check

x_out = x.detach().numpy() #Convert the Tensor input for numpy

sess = rt.InferenceSession("model1.onnx")
input_names = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
print(input_names)
output_names = sess.get_outputs()[0].name
print(output_names)
scores = sess.run([output_names], {input_names: x_out.astype(np.float32)})[0]
print(scores)
```

And it works beautifully, I get my output exactly as I expected when I compare with the output from Pytorch model. But when I try to load with OpenCV DNN with:

`net = cv2.dnn.readNet("model1.onnx")`

I get this error:
`error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:1073: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20221220::ONNXImporter::handleNode'

> Node [Pad@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!Pad_16) parse error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:591: error: (-5:Bad argument) Blob  not found in const blobs in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20221220::ONNXImporter::getBlob'
> `

I really misunderstood why I can load my model with ONNX Runtime and can't with OpenCV DNN. I already read about OpenCV DNN doesn't accept ONNX with dynamic inputs, but I think that's not my case, as I straightly set my input dimensions. Ideas for solving this?
Im using ONNX at 1.13, ONNXruntime at 1.14, OpenCV at 4.7.
My onnx model in Netron: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQMFC.jpg

Comment: onnx runtime has obviously implemented all the layers that are supported by ONNX. OpenCV hasn't yet implemented all the layer types.

Comment: The error is inlayer `onnx_node!Pad_16` which looks like opencv padding layer isnt compatible to onnx padding layer. Is it an asymmetric padding layer? https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20964

Comment: Hey Micka, thanks for the answer, you are right. This Pytorch model came from a conversion (keras/tensorflow-to-pytorch) and in TensorFlow we can do padding='same' in Conv2d. But pytorch doesn't support this operation, so I calculated the padding manually and unfortunately I got this asymmetric. The way I found to skip this, it's converting the same model (but in TensorFlow) to .onnx then loading in OpenCV DNN, it seems working fine at the moment.